# php development on a Mac, I have nginx already installed, what else do I need?

Tags: php, nginx

I have nginx installed (was using it for Ruby on rails with passenger).

What do I need to get this to work for PHP now?

Comment: Any reason why you want to use nginx? Apache or IIS are much easier to work with. At least during development.

Comment: Mac. MAC = http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/) for all my PHP/MYSQL on a Mac. Easy to install and get running. Runs separately from the built in Mac Apache server.

Comment: where is the built in apache server btw?

Comment: You have to enable the module in the http.conf file try this: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071030153912813

Comment: @esqw I'm gonna get MAMP pro - is it worth the cash? Can you run https?